# wrong count in count function with php

Tags: php, linux, count, explode

```
$checkvpn = trim(`sudo ifconfig | grep -i "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`);
$checkvpnstring = (string)$checkvpn;
$checkvpncount = count("\n",$checkvpnstring);
$checkvpncount++;
$checkvpnexplode = explode("\n", $checkvpnstring);

for($i=0;$i<=$checkvpncount;$i++){
    $ip = $checkvpnexplode[$i];
    if($ip == $externalip){
        $vpnconfigured = "yes";
        break;
    }
}
```

I have above code in which I get all ip which are available on my linux machine. But problem occurred when I have 13 ip and count only 3 and if I echo `$checkvpnexplode[12]` then it prints 13th ip address.

My question is why does the `count` function only count 3 and explode function give output of all.
I have used same function for both exploding and counting.

value of $checkvpn = 10.10.1.1 10.10.2.1 103.29.235.45 127.0.0.1

value of $checkvpnstring = 10.10.1.1 10.10.0.1 10.10.8.1 103.29.235.15 10.10.10.1 127.0.0.1 10.10.12.1 10.10.9.1 10.10.11.1 10.10.7.1 10.10.5.1 10.10.2.1 10.10.6.1 10.10.3.1 10.10.4.1

value of $checkvpnstring = 10.10.1.1 10.10.0.1 10.10.8.1 103.29.235.15 10.10.10.1 127.0.0.1 10.10.12.1 10.10.9.1 10.10.11.1 10.10.7.1 10.10.5.1 10.10.2.1 10.10.6.1 10.10.3.1 10.10.4.1

Comment: Can you show the value of `$checkvpn` or `$checkvpnstring`?

Comment: shouldn't you `count` after you `explode`? why do you `count` with parameters?, ex. `count("\n",$checkvpnstrin);` ?

Comment: I have give value @NijrajGelani

Comment: count gives you number of elements in an array, maybe you want substr_count() ?

Comment: `$checkvpncount = count("\n",$checkvpnstring);` is wrong; should be `$checkvpncount = count($checkvpnstring);` it looks like a copy paste error from your explode statement

Answer (score 0):

`$checkvpncount = count("\n",$checkvpnstring);` is wrong; should be `$checkvpncount = count($checkvpnstring);` it looks like a copy paste error from your explode statement

I have tested your code and made some small changes:

```
<?
$vpnconfigured = "no";
$externalip = "1.2.3.4";
$checkvpn = trim(`sudo ifconfig | grep -i "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`);
$checkvpnstring = (string)$checkvpn;
$checkvpncount = count($checkvpnstring);
$checkvpncount++;
$checkvpnexplode = explode("\n", $checkvpnstring);

for($i=0;$i<=$checkvpncount;$i++){
    $ip = $checkvpnexplode[$i];
    if($ip == $externalip){
        $vpnconfigured = "yes";
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($checkvpncount);
var_dump($checkvpnexplode);
var_dump($checkvpn);
echo $vpnconfigured;
?>
```

It appears  that your count was getting confused by the extra parameter;

the output is :

```
int(2)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "192.168.1.240"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
}
string(23) "192.168.1.240
127.0.0.1"
```

and my corresponding ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:192.168.1.240  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6501443 errors:0 dropped:7 overruns:0 frame:21
          TX packets:7860026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2026553110 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:5197150028 (4.8 GiB)
          Interrupt:18

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:146814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:146814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:25834701 (24.6 MiB)  TX bytes:25834701 (24.6 MiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below, there is no need to cast as string, or to count the way you do:

```
$ips = trim(`ifconfig | grep -i "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`);

$a = explode(PHP_EOL,$ips);

$trimmedArray = array_map('trim', $a); // trim again to remove internal new lines

print "we have " . count($trimmedArray) . " ips in total" . PHP_EOL;

foreach($trimmedArray as $ip){
    print $ip . PHP_EOL;
    // you can process each IP further here
}

print_r($trimmedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `count` function in PHP is used to count the number of elements in an array, whereas you are applying the `count` function on a string

See more information about `count()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Now, to achieve what you want, you first need to apply `explode` to the `$checkvpnstring` and convert it into an array and then apply the `count` function.

See more about `explode()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Like this:

```
$checkvpn = trim(`sudo ifconfig | grep -i "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`);
$checkvpnstring = (string)$checkvpn;
$checkvpnexplode = explode(" ", $checkvpnstring);
$checkvpncount = count($checkvpnexplode);

// Now, back to that loop
for($i=0;$i<=$checkvpncount;$i++){
    // Your rest of the logic
}
```